# Assign atoms in the Earth to a variable in Julia

Tags: julia

In Python 3.6, the following works to assign a variable an estimate of the atoms in the Earth:

```
In[6]: atoms_in_earth = 10**50
In[7]: atoms_in_earth
Out[7]: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

However, the following does not work in Julia 1.0.0:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = 10^50
-5376172055173529600

julia> atoms_in_earth = BigInt(10^50)
-5376172055173529600

julia> atoms_in_earth = BigFloat(10^50)
-5.3761720551735296e+18

julia> atoms_in_earth = big(10^50)
-5376172055173529600

julia> atoms_in_earth = big"10^50"
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid number format 10^50 for BigInt or BigFloat
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

I was able to get these methods to work:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = big"1_0000000000_0000000000_0000000000_0000000000_0000000000"
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

julia> float(ans)
1.0e+50

julia> atoms_in_earth = parse(BigInt, '1' * '0'^50)
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

julia> float(ans)
1.0e+50
```

I am hoping there is an easier way to do this in Julia.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia uses **native** integers by default, and these can overflow. Python uses **big** integers by default (of arbitrary precision, it's size limit depend of the amount of available memory) and does not overflow (but is slower because of this).

Your first example overflows for `Int64`:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = 10^50
-5376172055173529600
```

Your second, third and fourth examples, have already overflown, before you converted them to bigs:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = BigInt(10^50)
-5376172055173529600

julia> atoms_in_earth = BigFloat(10^50)
-5.3761720551735296e+18

julia> atoms_in_earth = big(10^50)
-5376172055173529600
```

Your fifth example is not a valid big literal:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = big"10^50"
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid number format 10^50 for BigInt or BigFloat
```

But you can create a small number as a `BigInt`, in your example `10` and any further operations will be promoted to **big** arithmetic, form then on:

```
julia> x = 10
10

julia> typeof(x)
Int64

julia> x = BigInt(10)
10

julia> typeof(x)
BigInt

julia> big(10) == big"10" == big(10)
true

julia> y = x^50
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

julia> typeof(y)
BigInt
```

In this case `50` gets promoted to a `BigInt` as well, before computing `x^50` and thus yielding a `BigInt` in the end.

```
julia> BigInt(10)^50 == big"10"^50 == big(10)^50
true
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
julia> atoms_in_earth = big"1e50"
1.0e+50

julia> typeof(ans)
BigFloat
```